# Regular expression in Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression for:
anyTwonumbers(dot)anyThreeNumbers(dot)anyThreeNumbers(dash)anyLetter

Examples: 19.789.324-J or 05.600.765-N

This is my code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}-[A-Z]{1}");

public void validate(String dni){
    Matcher m = p.matcher(dni);
    System.out.println(m.find());
}
```

The problem is that m.find() returns true when there is one or more letters (58.456.843-YL). I want it to return true when there is only one letter.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Use 'matches()' instead. And escape the dots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape the `.` (since dot is a wildcard to match any char but `\n`) and also you can leverage anchors (`^` and `$`) to match the exact content:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]{3}\\.[0-9]{3}-[A-Z]$");
```

If you want to shorten it a little more you can use:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\d{2}\\.\\d{3}\\.\\d{3}-[A-Z]$");
```

### Pattern & Matcher approach

You can use this code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\d{2}\\.\\d{3}\\.\\d{3}-[A-Z]$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

// check occurrence
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("ok");
}
```

### [String.matches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) approach

Btw, if you don't want to use the `Pattern` and `Matcher` objects, you could use something like this:

```
public void validate(String dni){
    System.out.println(dni.matches("^\\d{2}\\.\\d{3}\\.\\d{3}-[A-Z]$"));
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "escape the `.`" ?

That works great, thanks.

Comment: @anonymous then try "11x111x111-A" and see if it really works great.

Comment: a simple `.` means any character.. so, to make it act like a literal dot you should escape it with ```\```.. and in java you should also escape the escape character with ```\```. hence `\\.` :)

Comment: @anonymous The `.` matches any character you can have `19X789@324-J` and will pass, so you have to use `\\.` to explicitly have a dot

Comment: @anonymous "*What do you mean by "escape the ."?*" `.` is special character in regex representing any character (except line separators). Process of making this character simple literal (which will represent only itself - only dot character) is called escaping and can be achieved by adding ``\`` before it in regex engine (which in String needs to be written as `"\\"`).

Comment: @Tom m.find() returns false with "11x111xA", so yeah.

Comment: @anonymous did the answer help you?

Comment: @Fede Yes! I forgot to accept it as the best answer. Thank you very much, Fede.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regular expression:

```
Pattern.compile("\\d\\d\\.\\d\\d\\d\\.\\d\\d\\d-[a-zA-Z]$");
```